# Is there a way to import a layout with multiple partitions into ramdisk?

Tags: linux, partition-table, ramdisk, sfdisk

I dumped the partition layout of a disk, with:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda > part_table
cat part_table
```

output

```
label: dos
label-id: 0x0004bc49
device: /dev/sda
unit: sectors

/dev/sda1 : start=        2048, size=      131072, type=83
/dev/sda2 : start=      133120, size=      131072, type=83
/dev/sda3 : start=      264192, size=      131072, type=83
/dev/sda4 : start=      395264, size=   234045440, type=5
/dev/sda5 : start=      397312, size=      131072, type=af
/dev/sda6 : start=      530432, size=      131072, type=83
/dev/sda7 : start=      663552, size=      131072, type=83
/dev/sda8 : start=      796672, size=      131072, type=83
/dev/sda9 : start=      929792, size=      131072, type=7
```

Is there a way to import this partition layout into a ramdisk?

Comment: `sfdisk` can do this. `sfdisk /dev/ram < part_table`

Comment: @DougO'Neal Can you please add this as an answer so I can accept upvote after I test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sfdisk` output to create the new partition table

```
sfdisk /dev/ram <part_table
```

If you're really daring (or old-fashioned), you can also use `dd`

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/sda-mbr.bin bs=512 count=1
dd if=sda-mbr.bin of=/dev/ram0 bs=1 count=64 skip=446 seek=446
```

Comment: I have no `/dev/ram`, will come back here later when I discover why

Comment: I loaded it as a module `sudo modprobe brd rd_size=100000`